# iphone - the order of the touch (tap) event

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView and a UIWebView.

The UIWebView is a child view of the UIView.

The UIWebView contains a youtube video and is set as to let the video fit to the UIWebView.

I have a UITapGesture associated with the parent UIView for single tap, say, if a user single tap the whole view, it will invoke A.

So, when the UIWebView loads the youtube video, there is a button on top of the video waiting for users to click to play. But now if I click the button, the youtube is played, but also the A is invoked too. This is what I don't want.

How should I solve it?

I thought the touch/tap event should be in a order and if the button is clicked, it should absorb the event and not give the UIView any more.

I also tried to add another UIView under the UIWebView, and attach that gesture to the underlying view. However, it still doesn't work.

How can I do to let the button over the youtube video independent?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this code in your view's .m file (if you are using UIView, subclass it):

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint p = [self convertPoint:point toView:webView];
    if ([webView pointInside:p withEvent:event]) {
        return [webView hitTest:p withEvent:event];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Since I did not try this code, tell me if it doesn't work. There are still many ways to deal with the situation. :)

Comment: could you please tell me another way other than subclass views?

Comment: @JacksonTale Since you are using UITapGesture, you can also get where did the user tap at the screen, check if the point is in your UIWebView, if the answer is YES, you can just return your tap event function to stop further actions.

Comment: @xuzhe, but simply returning does not mean it will transfer the event to the webview, right?

Comment: It's not the UITapGesture's responsibility to transfer the event to the UIWebView. So, simple returning is fine.